# When using ruby-on-rails how do you iterate over variables stored in the session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I want to loop through all the variables stored in the session.  I checked and it appears that sessions are stored as a hash:
request.session.kind_of?(Hash) - returns true

I wasn't sure why the following code didn't work:
request.session.each {|key, value| puts keys + " --> " + value

I am trying to output all session variables as part of a debug view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
request.session.each {|key, value| puts keys + " --> " + value
```

Use:

```
request.session.each {|key, value| puts key.to_s + " --> " + value.to_s }
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. You have to use `request.session.to_hash`

Answer (score 1):

`<%= debug session %>` might be easier.

Use it like this:

```
<% if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'development' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'prototype' %>
           <%= debug session %>
           <%= debug params %>                   

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
request.session.to_hash.each{|key, value| puts "#{key.to_s} --> #{value.to_s}"}
```